# When is it OK to take powers of the equation of a curve?

Tags: calculus, parametric

Isnt raising curve equations to powers "dangerous" in general? Take

$$ x=y $$

if you square that, you get
$$x^2 = y^2$$

The new equation contains the points described by $ x=y $, and $ x=-y $ combined, ie, 2 lines, slopes 1 & -1, unlike the original equation that only described a single line.

I'm self-studying calculus currently, reached arclengths, and I find that I have to take powers of curve equations sometimes or I CANNOT solve a problem. Im always worried about unwanted solutions. Is there some easy way of telling when it's ok to take powers?

The particular problem I'm struggling with currently is one where I have to get an equation in $x$ & $y$ for this parametric equation for a curve ($k$ is a positive integer):

$$ x = a.cos^k (t) $$

$$ y = a.sin^k (t) $$

Is it valid to take the both sides to the power $2/k$ here? That would certainly help me solve this problem, but I'm not comfortable doing that, because I have no idea what kind of extra solutions will spawn, Im struggling to even imagine what it could be doing to the solution.

I'd be so grateful if anyone could help clear up this recurring doubt I'm having :⁠'⁠(.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, unless you have constraints to eliminate unwanted solution. For example if you have the constraint $x > 0$ then it's find to take the square root of both sides of $x^2 = y^2$, which is $x = |y|$.
You problem with the parametric curve can be solved though. Notice that $sin^2(t)$ and $cos^2(t)$ are non-negative, then:
$$(x^2)^{1/k}+(y^2)^{1/k} = (a^2)^{1/k}$$
Please remember that $(x^2)^{1/k}$ is not the same as $x^{2/k}$ for $x < 0$. You can also use the absolute value function:
$$|x|^{2/k}+|y|^{2/k} = |a|^{2/k}$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer! Constraints on x & y could eliminate extra solutions, got it. But how does the fact the sin^2 & cos^2 always being positive help? Sin^2 & cos^2 dont exist in the original equations. If you're trying to communicate that 1/k will always give an answer when performed on a square, I get that, but I'm afraid the confusion about possible extra solutions still exists in my mind.

Comment: @YeslinSequeira the constraint is $sin^2(t) + cos^2(t) = 1$. The corresponding value of $t$ exist if and only if this condition is satisfied. As long as a pair $(x,y)$ satisfy this relation, then it's a valid solution.

Comment: Ok, I'm still confused. First I think I need clarification on what 1/k does. In general, there could be multiple values that satisfy the 1/kth power, if k is even I believe? Because even means theres both a positive & negative real value that can satisfy to condition of being the result. So maybe we can implicitly impose the rule that 1/k gives the positive value incase of an even k. (Please correct any errors I may have made in my reasoning, Im very good at making mistakes).

Comment: Ok, now that I have a resolution of the multiple value confusion, on to the next source of confusion, does 2 spawn an extra solution? Yes, I believe it does. Does 1/k spawn new solutions? I have no clue how to go about answering that.

Comment: @YeslinSequeira formally speaking, $a^{1/n}$ maps a *nonnegative* number $a$ to a *unique, nonnegative* number $b$ such that $b^n = a$. So you cannot directly take rational power of $x$ and $y$ because that requires $x,y \geq 0$

Comment: @YeslinSequeira also $\root {n}\of{x}$ is not $x^{1/n}$ because $\root{n}\of{x}$ can be defined for odd $n$ and negative $x$ but $x^{1/n}$ is not

Comment: Ok, got it. This does offer some clarity to the meaning of the power, I wasn't aware of these conventions, so thank you for that! I'm still confused about possible extra solutions, I think I need some time to clear my head.

Answer (score 0):

After you square, everything becomes positive, so then you can take the $k$th root without any problem.  The equation $x=y$ implies $x^2=y^2$ though of course one cannot reverse the implication.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to help me out! I wanted some clarification on whether raising the equations to 2/k produces extra solutions. Now that you point it out, yeah, it seems like the operation itself will always give real numbers on both sides, but I'm still scared to do this particular thing in general, because I don't know if I'm creating new solutions.

Comment: As you pointed out in your question, squaring both sides may well create additional solutions.  It remains true however that $x=y$ implies $x^2=y^2$ (though the opposite implication is incorrect).  So if your goal is to obtain a relation between $x$ and $y$, you can certainly apply the squaring operation (though you can't apply the square root operation without care).

Comment: Ok, I get that raising both sides with the same power keeps the equation valid, so you get a valid relationship. But what I find a bit "awkward" I guess, is how new solutions may be created. What if I want the equation to uniquely describe the original curve, nothing else? Is there anything meaningful I can do with powers to that end?

Comment: You would have to consider separate cases depending on the signs of the variables.  Note that this is a very common problem, even when converting the equation of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ to being the graph of a function.